# Ansible format output for nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

I am trying to get jvm setting of the cluster but not sure how to parse the output. Could you please help me to sort this output in a tabular format and send in as email notification.

```
  msg:
nodes:
  0mvnn_mqprtst-okhla:
    jvm:
      mem:
        heap_committed: 16gb
        heap_committed_in_bytes: 17179869184
        heap_max: 16gb
        heap_max_in_bytes: 17179869184
        heap_used: 4.8gb
        heap_used_in_bytes: 5209695080
        heap_used_percent: 30
      uptime: 45.2d
    name: abc-node
  4xxNxXJLSN-la14KI6wMh3w:
    jvm:
      mem:
        heap_committed: 1gb
        heap_committed_in_bytes: 1073741824
        heap_max: 1gb
        heap_max_in_bytes: 1073741824
        heap_used: 349.3mb
        heap_used_in_bytes: 366369248
        heap_used_percent: 34
      uptime: 33.2d
    name: def-node
  612_2W0ER226_cqsq35O5V-H:
    jvm:
      mem:
        heap_committed: 16gb
        heap_committed_in_bytes: 17179869184
        heap_max: 16gb
        heap_max_in_bytes: 17179869184
        heap_used: 8.7gb
        heap_used_in_bytes: 9365826416
        heap_used_percent: 54
      uptime: 31.2d
    name: ghi-node
```

I tried the following.

```
- debug: msg="{{jsoncontent.content.nodes.*.name | from_yaml}}"
```

or

```
- debug: msg="{{jsoncontent.content.nodes.[0].name | from_yaml}}"
```

but getting the following error.

```
  msg: 'template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{jsoncontent.content.nodes.*.name | from_yaml}}'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either use *json_query*

```yaml
  names: "{{ nodes|json_query('*.name') }}"
```

, or convert the dictionary to a list and *map* the attribute

```yaml
  names: "{{ nodes|dict2items|
                   map(attribute='value.name') }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  names:
  - abc-node
  - def-node
  - ghi-node
```

Comment: I do not have nodes variable, code provided above is the result which is registered in jsoncontent variable.

Comment: Then, use `jsoncontent.content.nodes` instead of `nodes`. Make sure you understand what [mre] means.

Comment: thanks @vladimir, yes I do understand. but tried the same as well but giving the error.   msg: |-
    Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:
    'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'nodes'